# dynamically add item to angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that generates a drag/drop reorderable list with add and remove functionality.  If you click in the container, an input is added dynamically, you type in it and when you type a comma, the value you typed is pushed into the list used with ng-repeat to build the list.  (Should be kinda familiar to users of this site :) )

This works awesome when the initial object backing it is not null.  But when the object begins null and you try to add the first item (by detecting the null and scope.$apply the initialization)the markup is not generated.

Here is a plunk to show what I mean.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Momlgpfy82kHRPwXGR8V?p=preview

In my app, the data is coming from an external source, so I can't ensure non-null lists.  How can I get angular to properly respond to the array initialization (and later push)?

Comment: Why can't you set the initial list to `[]` instead of `null`?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller yes, I actually was already...turned out to be a bug in the way the directive was accessing the list...I actually needed `eval("scope." + attrs.draggableList) instead of `scope[attrs.draggableList]

Comment: You definitely don't want to use `eval` as that's not safe. Try `scope.$eval(attrs.draggableList)` instead: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope. But keep in mind that this isn't a two-way binding and it won't update if you change the list outside the directive. Your directive should use `$observe` and an isolate scope.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller Thanks for the suggestion, I made the eval change as you suggested and it works for what I need as there shouldn't be any external changes to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Set list to empty array...whenevr a new item is pushed into array angular listeners will update directive

http://plnkr.co/edit/h3GOpTX6Chh1wjcM9QrV?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, it turned out to be a bug in the directive.